# Did the medievals have a philosophy of childhood?

Tags: medieval

St. Augustine is last philosopher I know who treats childhood as interesting in the particular until Thomas Aquinas,* and after that it's basically straight on until Locke's theories of development and education. But this seems unlikely to me given what I take to be the the interesting questions around baptism, heredity, family, child saints, and biblical interpretation that might have presented themselves. I suspect my own ignorance, and not unreasonably, since I know so little.

Did medieval philosophers other than Augustine and Aquinas deal in detail with philosophical questions about children and the nature of childhood? If so, what are the major thinkers or books I should be looking at?

**With the exception of Philosophus and Theologus Autodidactus.*

Comment: You may be interested in the recent volume [Childhood in History. Perceptions of Children in the Ancient and Medieval Worlds](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/e/9781315571133).

Comment: @Conifold: That looks useful, thank you.